# Django filter argument based on foreign key value

Tags: python, django, filter, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I am trying to filter a queryset based on a `DateField` filter using an argument from a foreign key. So if the `Server.updated` difference in days from today is greater than `Support.update_days`, then it should be included. I'm having trouble using the `Support.update_days` as the value within the query.

The model definitions:

```
class Support(models.Model):
    update_days = models.IntegerField()

class Server(models.Model):
    updated = models.DateField()
    support = models.ForeignKey(Support)
```

In the view:

```
server_list = Server.objects.filter(updated__gte=
    date.today() - timedelta(days=Use Support.update_days value here))
```

I have tried:

```
server_list = Server.objects.filter(updated__gte=
    date.today() - timedelta(days=F('support__update_days')))
```

But it doesn't work and returns a type error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no relationship between each row of `Server` and `Support`. Is there just one `Support` object that you want to use when filtering `Servers`s?

Comment: Sorry, there is a foreignkey relationship in there. My mistake, I just didn't include it in the code. Edited to reflect.